# Can I use hibernate for data centric applications?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, object-oriented-database

I wag going through a [hibernate tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/introduction.shtml), where they say that hibernate is not suitable for data centric application. I am very much impressed by the 'object oriented structure' it gives to the program, but my application is very much data centric(it fetches and updates huge number of records. But I dont use any stored procedures). Cant I use hibernate?Are there any wrappers written over hibernate, which I can use for my application?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about specific meaning of phrase `data centric`. Aren't all database applications `data centric`? However, if you do process tons of data, Hibernate may not be the best choice. Hibernate is best to represent object models mapped to the database and it may have role in any application, but to do ETL (extract/transform/load) tasks you may need to write very efficient SQL by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you have guessed, data centric, I meant processing huge data. But are there any wrappers available to use hibernate in such situations?

Comment: @hnm You don't need wrappers. You can use Hibernate directly. But it's not very efficient. You can always set up Hibernate infrastructure for less intensive cases and you can use native SQL with Hibernate for heavy data processing. I am a big fun of Hibernate, by the way, but I am realistic about its limitations.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In principal you can, but it tends to be slow. Hibernate more or less creates an object for every row retrieved from the database. If you do this with large volumes of data, performance takes a serious hit. Also updates on many rows using a single update have only very basic support.

A wrapper won't help, at least with the object creation issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages of using Hibernate, when one gets their object model correct as a developer there is a lot of appeal in interacting with the database via objects but in practice I have found initially Hibernate is great but becomes very frustrating when you come against issues like performance and fault finding.

When it comes to decision on the DA (Data Access) layer I ask myself this question.
Am I writing an application which has a requirement to run an different databases?

If the answer is yes then I will consider an (ORM) like Hibernate. 
If its no then I will normally just use JDBC normally via Spring.

I feel that interacting with the database via JDBC is a lot more transparant and easier to find faults and performance tune.